# Very confused by MySQL query results

Tags: mysql

So I'm not the best at SQL I have this complicated MySQL query that I'm lost in. The part I don't understand is, all of the results that come out of the partial query above UNION are multiplied by 8. How is this possible? Why are they being multiplied by 8 and how can I stop it? I also have a few other queries very similar to this one and they all have this same problem. Any ideas on why this could be happening would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
SELECT best_thrown
    FROM(
        SELECT CASE WHEN rageup_echelon.party_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN rageup_echelon.echelon_vote = 1 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN rageup_echelon.echelon_vote = 0 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) END AS best_thrown
        FROM rageup_parties LEFT JOIN rageup_echelon ON rageup_parties.party_id = rageup_echelon.party_id
                            LEFT JOIN rageup_team_hosts ON rageup_parties.party_team_id = rageup_team_hosts.team_id
        WHERE rageup_team_hosts.team_id = 1 || rageup_team_hosts.team_id = 2 || rageup_team_hosts.team_id = 3
        AND rageup_parties.party_status = 'approved'
        AND rageup_parties.party_invites = 'public'
        AND rageup_team_hosts.user_id = 1
        GROUP BY rageup_parties.party_id
        UNION
        SELECT CASE WHEN rageup_echelon.party_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN rageup_echelon.echelon_vote = 1 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN rageup_echelon.echelon_vote = 0 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) END AS best_thrown
        FROM rageup_parties LEFT JOIN rageup_echelon
        ON rageup_parties.party_id = rageup_echelon.party_id
        WHERE rageup_parties.party_host_id = 1
        AND rageup_parties.party_status = 'approved'
        AND rageup_parties.party_invites = 'public'
        AND rageup_parties.party_team_id = 'user'
        GROUP BY rageup_parties.party_id
        ORDER BY best_thrown DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging, run just the first query without the `GROUP BY` stuff and look at the underlying rows that are returned.

Also note that you're using `LEFT JOIN from rageup_parties` to `rageup_team_hosts` - making matching `team_hosts` entries optional - but then requiring `team_id` to be set to non-NULL values in the `WHERE` clause.  If you know the data is dirty enough to require the `LEFT JOIN`, move those conditions into the `ON` clauses for each `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you for responding so fast Alain. I tried SELECTing * and took away the GROUP BY. That helped me out a little bit. It returned each result 8 times each, with the only difference in the rows being that the index of the team_hosts table counts from 1 to 8. And those 8 rows in the team_hosts table all have the same value "1" for both the team_id column and user_id column. That definitely explains something but I still have no idea how to fix it. And i'll move those conditions to the ON clause, thanks, I dont believe that's the exact problem here though.

Comment: So basically how can I get this query to just check the team_hosts table for the team_id and user_id but not use every row that has the correct team_id and user_id; just one row?

Comment: Haha the problem actually was with the ON clause. Thanks!